# How does Nessus send remote commands on Windows without RDP?

Tags: windows, python, nessus

I would like to know how Nessus sends remote commands on Windows. I have a scan with credentials launched on a Windows machine without RDP enabled, and Nessus can launch commands (.audit with the item PowerShell). How is this possible?

Is it possible send commands using SMB or NetBIOS?

**EDIT**
I want to do the same with python: connect to the host and run a command. I think Nesuss is using SMB with DCERPC. Some example or idea?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that Nessus, and similar scanners or other utilities, may remotely control or alter systems without RDP enabled. In fact, you'll probably be hard-pressed to find any remote management utility or vulnerability scanner that *requires* RDP.

Remote Desktop is mainly for the human user. Graphical interfaces help us to more easily interpret and manipulate data and control elements. However, automated tools have no such needs. In fact, a graphical interface would just slow them down. So, for these things, there are other protocols and programming interfaces available which allow them to remotely read and manipulate data and settings without a GUI getting in the way.

Depending on the system's configuration, its inherent vulnerabilities, and the information (e.g.: credentials) provided to the scanner, one or more of the following may have been used:

- Remote Registry
- Administrative Shares/SMB (e.g.: `\\ComputerName\C$\`)
- WMI
- PowerShell Remoting

Those are just some of the most commonly-used features that might be available remotely from a Windows system. Even if one of these doesn't give a tool the access it needs, it could be useful to drop in a custom utility (e.g.: Meterpreter) that *does*.

If you want to know for sure how Nessus is accessing the system for a specific test, your best bet is to look at the script definition and check the appropriate reference materials for the tool. Or, you could hook up a sniffer like WireShark and see what traffic is being passed.

Comment: Thanks. I ran a WireShark and the main protocols are: NetBios Session Service (86%) and DCE/RPC (4%). So I think Nessus is using SMB with DCE/RPC. I searching a way of replicate this with a python program or rpcclient. But I can't find something like smb.sendComand(...).

Answer (score 1):

Software such as [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) allow remote command execution without software on the remote system:

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute
>   processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for
>   console applications, without having to manually install client
>   software. PsExec's most powerful uses include launching interactive
>   command-prompts on remote systems and remote-enabling tools like
>   IpConfig that otherwise do not have the ability to show information
>   about remote systems.

Comment: What protocols is using PsExec?

Comment: @NessusNoob: The SMB protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Nessus appears to use SMB and WMI when doing credentialed scans. Take a look at the following PDF from their site: http://static.tenable.com/documentation/nessus_credential_checks.pdf